# How can I find scholarships for college in my area?

Tags: college, scholarship

There are tons of scholarship websites listed on Google, but they don't seen to contain the same data. Is there someplace I can go to view a more comprehensive database? I'm especially interested in finding scholarships available locally based on my home or college location.

Comment: How about exploring the financial aid section on the college website ? Normally colleges providing aid have this section on their websites.

Comment: Not sure how old you are, but if you're in high school, your high school will likely have a counselor who can direct you to useful information.  If not, then as DumbCoder said you may have luck asking at individual colleges.  For finding local scholarships, the best approach is to find knowledgeable people in your local area (e.g., counselors).  There is no truly comprehensive database since there is no centralized "register" of scholarships.

Answer (score 2):

Financial aid offices on campus should be able to help you out a ton with that sort of stuff. Also, you might just want to try looking up random scholarships using search engines and/or specialized sites that keep up with that sort of info. A lot of scholarships don't necessarily require proximity to where they are housed and can be applied to from anywhere, regardless of locality.